# create a list from values in array of objects

Tags: python, json

how i make a list from the values inside urban only for type gasolina?

```
{ ... "fuelUse" : {
        "urban" : [ 
            {
                "value" : 6.2,
                "unit" : "km/l",
                "type" : "alcool"
            }, 
            {
                "value" : 8.9,
                "unit" : "km/l",
                "type" : "gasolina"
            }
        ],
},
...."fuelUse" : {
        "urban" : [ 
            {
                "value" : 7.8,
                "unit" : "km/l",
                "type" : "alcool"
            }, 
            {
                "value" : 10.4,
                "unit" : "km/l",
                "type" : "gasolina"
            }
        ],
}
}
```

the output like: list = [ 8.9 , 10.4 ]

i tried to iterate in that way, but hav key error: 1

```
for c in cars:
   for a in c['fuelUse']['urban']:
      list.append(a[1]['value'])
```

Comment: can you please share the entire structure of your dict

Comment: because like this it is not valid as you have two times the same key in a dict

Comment: In the inner for loop when you print `a` is it what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
list.append(a['value'])
```

instead of

```
list.append(a[1]['value'])
```

Since `a` is not a list, it is a single object, there is no need for further indexing.

---

If you would like the value of the second element, which type is gasolina, from each `urban`, you should loop through them, not the object's inside.

```
for c in cars:
   for a in c['fuelUse']['urban']:
      if a['type'] == 'gasolina':
          list.append(a['value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure as you did not provide the entire data structure but according to your try it could be like this:

```
output = [x.get("value") for car in cars for x in car.get("fuelUse").get("urban") if x.get("type") == "gasolina"]
```